# MIT ps1c.py code does not get multiplication rigth

Tags: python, multiplication, arithmetic-expressions

I'm getting a multiplication error in my code (the product gets so much larger than expected).
I already searched for similar code that works and they are quite similar to mine.

Mine is the following:

```
portionDownPayment = 0.25
currentSavings = 0.0
r = 0.04
months = 36

semiAnnualRaise = 0.07
totalCost = 1000000

annualSalary = float(input("Enter your annual salary: "))

toPay = annualSalary * portionDownPayment

epsilon = 100

floor = 0
top = 100000



while True:
    portionSaved = (floor + top) / 2.0
    print("PortionSaved:", portionSaved / 100000.000)
    currentSavings = 0
    for x in range(1, 37):
        currentSavings += ((annualSalary/1200000) * (portionSaved)) + (currentSavings*r/12)
        months += 1
        if months % 6 == 0:
            annualSalary = (annualSalary) + annualSalary * semiAnnualRaise

    print("Current Savings:", currentSavings)
    print("To pat:", toPay)
    print()

    if abs(currentSavings - toPay) <= epsilon:
        print("Perfect savings rate:", portionSaved / 10000)
        break

    if currentSavings < toPay:
        floor = portionSaved
    elif currentSavings > toPay:
        top = portionSaved

    if top == floor:
        print("Imposible to calculate savings rate with this parameters")
        break
```

In console, the prompting (just a extract were i found the problem) is the following:

```
PortionSaved: 0.00390625
Current Savings: 75913.48485232962
To pat: 75000.0

PortionSaved: 0.001953125
Current Savings: 56962.83541626017
To pat: 75000.0

PortionSaved: 0.0029296875
Current Savings: 128228.7840548412
To pat: 75000.0
```

As you can see, when multiplied by 0.0029296875, the current savings gets so much larger than when multiplied by 0.00390625.

Also, this is my first post, any advice on posting is welcome.

Comment: Try printing values/comparisons at different places to see what is happening during execution. ... [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I imagine the purpose of taking MIT 6.0 is to learn. Part of that learning is how to debug your programs. Be methodical. Write down on paper what you think you are doing (step-by-step) and compare it to what you are actually doing. there is a lesson later on about debugging, it may be worthwhile watching that one. Welcome to SO. Be sure to  take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Thanks! There were a lot of problems with my previous code. I've already figured it out. Thanks for the resource on debugging. Should I delete the post?

Comment: Migtht as well delete it unless you want to answer yourself: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)